# How to use Paginator with pluck method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have several columns that are plucked out of database and displayed in a table.I have been trying to paginate the table.Is there a way where I could paginate each and every column values that are plucked out of database?

```
return $this-> orderByDesc('date_added')->whereNull('deleted_at')->pluck('program');
```

Comment: post your query

Comment: Here is the query that  plucks out the program column from the database:-      return $this->
                     orderByDesc('date_added')->whereNull('deleted_at')->pluck('program');

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Paginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html) instance with the query results and return that to your view with the table:

```
$page = 1;
$perPage = 10;
$options = [];
$items = $this-> orderByDesc('date_added')->whereNull('deleted_at')->pluck('program');

return view('some.table', [
    'items' => new LengthAwarePaginator($items->take($perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options)
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$page_no = 1;
$no_of_data = 10;
$offset = ($page_no * $no_of_data) - $no_of_data;
return $this-> orderByDesc('date_added')->whereNull('deleted_at')->offset($offset)->limit($no_of_data)->pluck('program');
```